# Preview de upload em modal

Tags: javascript, html5, node.js, angular

Estava fazendo preview através de outra aba:

```
public visualizarArquivo(file): void {
    var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(file);
    var a = document.createElement("a");
    a.setAttribute("href", url);
    a.setAttribute("target", "_blank");
    a.click();
  }
```

Mas tive problema com bloqueio de Pop up, agora preciso carregar esse preview em um modal, como carrego através de embed ou iframe ?